# Split on whitespaces in keys of dict, take value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary which has this form:

```
myDict = {'foo': bar, 'foobar baz': qux}
```

Now, I want to split on whitespaces in the key of the dict, make it the next key and take the value (duplicate).

```
myDictRev1 = {'foo': bar, 'foobar': qux, 'baz': qux}
```

Comment: Great, so what have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use dictionary comprehensions like this:

```
>>> myDict = {'foo': 'bar', 'foobar baz': 'qux'}
>>> {k:v for k, v in myDict.items() for k in k.split()}
{'baz': 'qux', 'foo': 'bar', 'foobar': 'qux'}
```